# Multiple classes java

Tags: java

So i'm awfully new to coding but i quite like it, i'm really young so i have 0 experience on related stuff.
I'm watching this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqTg2buXS5o) series about java code and in this episode: 
he creates another class and uses it in the main one but im on intelij(not eclipse as he is) and it gave me two errors saying java couldnt find the symbol (my second class);
my code:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        tuna tunaObject = new tuna();
        tunaObject.simpleMessage(null);
    }
```

Second class:

```
 public class tuna{
        public void simpleMessage(){
            System.out.println("Another class");
        }
    }
```

Comment: By convention, class names should start with capitals.

Answer (score 4):

Your simple message method does not accept parameters, so don't try to pass in any. Instead of calling `simpleMessage(null)` simply call `simpleMessage()`.

Also either make sure that the `tuna` class is located in the same package as your main class, or import the `tuna` class via an `import` statement above the `Main` class and below the `package` declaration. Even if the two source files are in the same physical directory, the Java compiler won't understand which class you are referring to unless you specifically define each class in the same package.

Adjust your second class to:

```
package com.company;
public class tuna{
      public void simpleMessage(){
          System.out.println("Another class");
      }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and doesnt appear to make any diference.Its just not finding the clas no idea why

Comment: Are both classes defined in the same package?

Comment: Thanks so much, migrated the tuna class to the main class and it worked. You were right, besides being in the same directory it didnt recognized it.

Comment: You're very welcome! As you endeavor further into the world of programming, understand that every little thing you do must be very specific!

Comment: Understood that now!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wecome to Java.

Maybe you can confirm first that the second class is located in the same package with the `Main`. And it is better to claim a class in `First letter upper-cased` format.

Comment: Thanks.It was in the second directory but wasnt on the main class!